# POST http://localhost:8080/places 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, token

The problem occurs in my api, inside my api I have created a CRUD, to be able to execute the CRUD I have a token that I save in the Cookies, I have tested the program in Postman and the token is saved in the Cookies, the CRUD operations if they work correctly, but when using the API in my client (React), it fails to save the token in cookies:

This is my login code:

```
export const login = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!user) return next(createError(404, "User not found!"));

    const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
      req.body.password,
      user.password
    );

    if (!isPasswordCorrect)
      return next(createError(400, "Wrong password or username!"));

    const token = jwt.sign(
      { id: user._id, isAdmin: user.isAdmin },
      process.env.JWT
    );

    const { password, isAdmin, ...otherDetails } = user._doc;
    res
      .cookie("access_token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
      })
      .status(200)
      .json({ details: { ...otherDetails }, isAdmin });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

this is my token verification code:

```
export const verifiedToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.access_token;
  if (!token) {
    return next(createError(401, "You are not authenticated!"));
  }

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return next(createError(403, "Token is not valid!"));
    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
};
```

This is the route code:

```
//create
router.post("/", verifiedUser, createPlace);
```

On the client side, this is the login code (in data I send the password and email )
So far the code works fine
:

```
const handleLogin = async() => {
    try {
      await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/auth/login", data);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  };
```

and this is my register code (in input passed all the information of the product):

```
const handleSubmit= () =>{
        const place = await axios.post(inputs)
        console.log(place)
}
```

the error returns "POST http://localhost:8080/places 401 (Unauthorized)" and You are not authenticated!.I don't understand why the error appears, but in Postman it works correctly.

Comment: It's pretty obvious from the 401 error that there is no access token in the cookies.  You can debug this yourself by looking at the cookies being sent with the axios request either in the network tab in the browser inspector or by logging the cookies on the server.  My guess would be that you need the `withCredentials: true` option for `axios()` so that it will include cookies.  But, it's also possible that this client just doesn't yet have the token as a cookie or the it's on a different domain.

Comment: When logging in to Postman, the token is generated and saved in cookies, but in the client the cookies appear empty.

Comment: Did you try the `withCredentials` option with your  `axios` call as in `await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/auth/login", data, {withCredentials: true});`?

Comment: I just did it and it's the same error, nothing appears in the cookies

Comment: Do you know how to use the browser dev console to examine cookies in the browser and see exactly what is coming back from the server and what is being sent to the server?  This is how you diagnose as problem like this.

Comment: I found a solution on this page: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/react-authentication-how-to-store-jwt-in-a-cookie-346519310e81.

Comment: the problem is that I must have a proxy in my package.json file, I don't know what it means to have a proxy there to make the request directly, but thank you very much for your help @jfriend00, but the problem still continues.